# Help with SOQL grouping

Tags: soql, controller

I have a requirement where I need to display top records from an object instead of all that meets the criteria. Below is my SOQL

```
SELECT  CustomAccount__r.Name, CustomAccount__r.Country__c, Month__c, 
                             Account_Range__c FROM Custom_Month__c WHERE Account_Range__c != 0 AND
                             CustomAccount__r.UpDate__c = TRUE AND Date__c >= LAST_MONTH
```

Below is the result that I'm getting with the above SOQL
[image: Without Grouping]

From the above result, I need to display only top records instead of all 4. It is as follows.
[image: With Grouping]

When I tried to group the query using Name, Account_Range__c and Month__c, I am recieving the error as

> MALFORMED_QUERY: duplicate alias: Name

Can anyone help me out on this to display only top records of an account instead of multiple records?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CustomAccount__r.Name, CustomAccount__r.Country__c, Month__c, 
       Account_Range__c FROM Custom_Month__c 
WHERE Account_Range__c != 0 AND CustomAccount__r.UpDate__c = TRUE AND Date__c >= LAST_MONTH 
ORDER BY Account_Range__c DESC, Account_Range__c DESC
```

Use above query and the first record will the largest.

Comment: I need only the large ones from Test Account 1 and Test Account 2 to be fetched instead of displaying the top ones first. Please suggest

Comment: Take List<Custom_Month__c > monthList = query;

then monthList[0] will be largest

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregate MAX SOQL function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm).

You can use below query to get maximum values per account:

```
SELECT  CustomAccount__r.Name AccountName, MAX(Account_Range__c) MaxRange
FROM Custom_Month__c 
WHERE Account_Range__c != 0 AND CustomAccount__r.UpDate__c = TRUE AND Date__c >= LAST_MONTH 
GROUP BY CustomAccount__r.Name
```

Note that you should either aggregate a field or group the field and so you should not use `CustomAccount__r.Country__c` field.